# Equivalent of ObjectContext.AddObject(entityName, entity) on DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net, upgrade, entity-framework-5

I upgraded an old project started in `ef4` but now I migrated it to `ef5`.

This is the old code:

```
protected void SaveEntity<T>(T entity)
{
        using (DocsManagerContainer context = new DocsManagerContainer())  
                {  
                    string entityType = typeof(T).ToString();  
                    GetLogger().LogMessage("Save " + entityType + " started", LogLevel.Info);  
                    DbTransaction transaction = null;  
                    try  
                    {  
                        context.Connection.Open();  
                        transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();  
                        context.AddObject(typeof(T).Name + "s", entity);  
                        transaction.Commit();  
                        context.SaveChanges();  
                    }  
                    catch (Exception e)  
                    {  
                        GetLogger().LogMessage("Save " + entityType + " thrown error :", e, LogLevel.Error);  
                        throw e;  
                    }  
                    finally  
                    {  
                        context.Connection.Close();  
                        transaction = null;  
                    }  
                    GetLogger().LogMessage("Save " + entityType + " ended", LogLevel.Info);  
                }  
    }
```

I've upgraded almost all of the code except : `context.AddObject(typeof(T).Name + "s", entity);`, but this isn't supported anymore.
How can I upgrade this ?

p.s. I do want to use generic code, not to use switches to add the corresponding object to correct `ObjectSet`
p.s. Error if I use .Set().Add(entity) is :

```
Error   2   The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.DbContext.Set<TEntity>()' D:\work\DocsManager\trunk\DocsManagerDataMapper\EF4Factory\BaseEF4Factory.cs    64  21  DocsManagerDataMapper
```

Comment: `DbContext` or `ObjectContext`? With `DbContext` you can use `context.Set<T>().Add(entity);`

Comment: I want to use DBContext for that, not object context as I stated in the question.

Comment: I want to be able to use DbContext.[...].AddObject(EntityName, entity); or something similar if it's possible.

Comment: see my answer (same as my comment).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With DbContext you can use `context.Set<T>().Add(entity)`;

Example: `context.Set<User>()` is equivalent to `context.Users` so `context.Set<User>().Add(myUser)` is equivalent to `context.Users.Add(myUser)`.

You want something closer  to this:

```
protected void SaveEntity<T>(T entity)
    where T : class
{
    using (DocsManagerContainer context = new DocsManagerContainer())  
    {  
        DbTransaction transaction = null;  
        try  
        {  
            context.Connection.Open();  
            transaction = context.Connection.BeginTransaction();  
            context.Set<T>().Add(entity);  
            transaction.Commit();  
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }  
        finally  
        {  
            context.Connection.Close();  
                transaction = null;  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I use something like this :  context.Set<T>().Add(entity); It will throw a Compile error. Please look at my edit of the question.

Comment: You may need to add generic constraint `where T : class` to your method. What's the compile error?